# What storyline do the characters in "The Death and Return of Superman" game follow?

Tags: dc, superman, the-death-and-return-of-superman

This was a SNES game from the late 90s, where you get to play as several different Supermen.

- Superman
- Superboy
- Man of Steel
- The Eradicator
- Cyborg Superman
- Superman in Black

Was this game following a storyline, or several stories? I'm familiar with the story of Superman vs Doomsday-and I know that Superboy has different powers, but who were the others and what stories did they follow, if any?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Well, I never played the game, but considering all the hints you are dropping in your question I'd say that the game was, nearly certainly, following the storyline of...drums rolls...The Death of Superman :-D

The entire storyline of The Death of Superman included both his death (by graceful courtesy of Doomsday), the appearance of four new "Supermen", and, finally, his resurrection (of sort).

The exact story arcs, in publication order, are:

- Doomsday!
- Funeral for a Friend
- [Reign of the Supermen](https://www.dccomics.com/graphic-novels/the-death-and-return-of-superman-1992/superman-reign-of-the-supermen)

And about your list:

**Superman**
Well, the man himself. The one who fights Doomsday. The one who dies (nearly).

**Superboy**
[image: Superboy]
Uh, yes, [Superboy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Superboy_(Kon-El)). A clone of Supes created by Cadmus. A partial clone, because good luck obtaining the DNA of Superman, so the original DNA had "holes" that were filled by Cadmus, hence his powers are partially due to a form of telekinesys.

**Man of Steel**
[image: Steel]
John Henry Irons, AKA [Steel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steel_(John_Henry_Irons)). First a top level scientist, then retired to be a constructions worker, saved by Supes one day, he decides to take the mantle on his shoulders after Superman death.

**Viator(?)**
[image: Eradicator]
I think you may mean [Eradicator](https://www.dcuniverse.com/encyclopedia/eradicator/), aka the Superman With The **Visor**. I'm not going to write a synopsis of it, too, because it's way too long and convoluted. Let's just say it was a kryptonian probe tasked with the mission of preserving the Kryptonian lifestyle.

**Cyborg Superman**
[image: CyborgSuperman]
Hank Henshaw, often just [Cyborg](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hank_Henshaw). Take the Fantastic Four, have all of them except one die instead of getting incredible powers, and have the one who survives thinks it's Superman fault. When Superman dies, he decides to take his revenge by pretending to be him reborn and then destroy his reputation.

**Superman in Black**
[image: Superman in pajama]
Our big blue boyscout himself, recovered from his death, only this time in a temporary suit which is basically his kryptonian hospital pajama, and a legendary mullet.

Comment: Thank you, yes it was the Eradicator. Too bad they didn't make it into a movie!

Comment: @KingofNES I guess you're not counting the animation: https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7167686/

Comment: I didn't even know there was one....Thank you!